PrimeVue DataTable - Get array results after filter is applied
I am using Vue via via CDN to add progressive reactivity to a few pages in an existing website. I have found the PrimeView DataTable which seems very capable and offers comprehensive filter functionality. The filtering is working fine via the UI, but when the user applies a filter, I cannot figure out how to get the list of rows in the current filter.
This is pretty much the same question as here: Filtered array in PrimeVue datatable?
The accepted answer does not explain how to access the methods/properties from javascript. I have tried the Vue.js devtools but still cannot find the answer

Filters are stored as an object in your local state. Try using the
Vue.js devtools extension to see the format of that object.

How do I get the filtered array from the DataTable when using the built-in filters property?
Here is a simple example. The filter "bob" is applied using the filters property of the DataTable. When the user clicks the "Show Alert" button, the alert should show all the customers in the currently filtered list (Bob Smith, Bob Jones and Bob Tailor)


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/primevue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@primevue/themes/umd/aura.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="customerFilters['global'].value" />
  Searching for: {{customerFilters['global'].value}}

  <p-datatable :value="customers" :filters="customerFilters">
    <p-column field="fullname" header="Full Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="sales" header="Total Sales"></p-column>
  </p-datatable>

  <button @click="showAlert">Show Alert</button>
</div>

<script>
  const { createApp, ref } = Vue

  const customers = ref([
    { fullname: "Bob Smith", sales: 11 },
    { fullname: "Bob Jones", sales: 22 },
    { fullname: "Bob Tailor", sales: 33 },
    { fullname: "Fred Bloggs", sales: 44 },
    { fullname: "Fred Baker", sales: 55 },
    { fullname: "Tom Peterson", sales: 66 },
  ])

  const customerFilters = ref({
    global: { value: "Bob", matchMode: PrimeVue.FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
  })

  function showAlert() {
    let filteredCustomers = [] // ???
    let str = "Customers in filter: "
    // str += filteredCustomers[0]["fullname"] + ", "
    // str += filteredCustomers[1]["fullname"] + ", "
    // str += filteredCustomers[2]["fullname"]
    alert(str) // "Customers in filter: Bob Smith, Bob Jones, Bob Tailor"
  }

  const app = createApp({
    setup() {
      return {
        customers,
        customerFilters,
        showAlert
      }
    },
  })

  app.use(PrimeVue.Config, {
    theme: {
      preset: PrimeVue.Themes.Aura
    }
  })

  app.component("p-datatable", PrimeVue.DataTable)
  app.component("p-column", PrimeVue.Column)

  app.mount("#app")
</script>



Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kq4sr85u/14/
Or am I going about this completely the wrong way? Would it be better to use a computed to filter the array in the view-model and bind the DataTable to the computed, filtered array. I know this would work but it seems crazy when the PrimeVue DataTable has all the advanced filter functionality already baked-in out the box.

What do you mean by "The accepted answer does not explain how to access the methods/properties from javascript" exactly? The https://primevue.org/datatable/#api.datatable.events.DataTableFilterEvent event has the filtered collection as the "event. filteredValue" property, which should be the list of filteredCustomers in your case.

@MrOnlineCoder; The text you are referring to is not the accepted answer. Adding an event handler to intercept the filter every time seems crazy. I only want to retrieve the filtered array in the cases where I need it. The accepted answers says that this can be done but the poster does not explain how.

Unfortunately, it seems that PrimeVue did not document a way to access filtered data directly, which is indeed strange for such a powerful component. However, it is still possible to do that in the following way:

Create a template ref and attach your DataTable to it:

const datatable = useTemplateRef('datatable');

<p-datatable :value="customers" :filters="customerFilters" ref="datatable">
...
</p-datatable>


Because DataTable is a options-API based component, you can directly access all it's data, methods and computed properties. According to source code (https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/2ebda30c1048bf989c1f37d8b17f91f071d25fa5/packages/primevue/src/datatable/DataTable.vue#L2015), processedData computed property is the one you are looking for:

const showAlert = () => {
  let filteredCustomers = datatable.value.processedData  
  let str = "Customers in filter: "
  str += filteredCustomers.map(customer => customer.fullname).join();
  alert(str)
}

As an alternative, you can use the event-based approach, and just store the latest known event.filteredValue in a ref:
const filteredRows = ref([])

const onDatatableFilter = event => {
  filteredRows.value = event.filteredValue
}

const showAlert = () => {
  //access filteredRows.value
}


I have created an updated fiddle for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/293ot74d/

Many thanks for this. It works perfectly. I thought that the component would expose the array of filtered rows via the api. I didn't think of getting a ref directly to the component.

It seems like an odd way to access the data but I guess their logic is that filtering is completely view-specific and should not cause side effects in the view-model. I can kind of understand the argument but even so, there are times when you want to work on only the records the user has currently filtered. I suspect the PrimeVue team would argue that you should be using the RowSelector for this job. I am completely new to PrimeVue but from what I have seen so far, it is a fantastic library.

@njr101 it's not common for Vue components to expose data "upwards", they usually accept data as props from parent and emit events to parent only. Therefore, one of possibilities is that PrimeVue decided that filter event would be enough to cover cases such as yours
